# jQuery Queue - Two Separate Animations on Same Object

Tags: jquery, animation, queue, fade

I'm making a small plugin that allows for site-wide notifications.

A notification (with default options) will wait (delay) for 6 seconds before fading out over 1 second.

But! Clicking it manually would make it fadeOut immediately for .5 seconds.

Here's my problem.

Clicking the notification would make it wait the 6 seconds delay before fading out. I want it to be immediate. I realized this should be done with queues, but I can't manage to understand them. Here's what I have so far:

```
$('#wpnotify')
    .click(function() {
        $(this).fadeOut(this.options.manualFade.dur, function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});


if (this.options.autoFade != false)
    $('#wpnotify')
        .delay(this.options.autoFade.delay, 'autoclose')
        .queue('autoclose', function(next) {
            $(this).fadeOut(this.options.autoFade.dur, function() {
                $(this).remove();
                    next();
                });
         }).dequeue('autoclose');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.stop(true,true)` to stop the queue and go to end immediately.

```
$('#wpnotify')
    .click(function() {
        $(this).stop(true,true).fadeOut(this.options.manualFade.dur, function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Is that alongside the queue or can that come instead of it?

Comment: I don't think you can execute an animation ignoring the queue, if something is already in the queue, it would have to finish before the next item in the queue can run.

Comment: I just disabled the queue, so it went back to the default fx queue - and this worked perfectly! Thanks :) Accepting in 2 mins when it lets me

Comment: OH i see, i didn't even notice the custom queue you were using. `.stop("autoclose",true,true);` would stop it.